# Error saving .asc bias file in R

Tags: raster, r, ascii, esri-ascii-raster, maxent

I used the following code to create a bias file in R for MaxEnt. I am able to create the bias file, but I am not able to save it as ascii (see error message). My lat/lon csv file contains only points located within Kenya, and the variable I used to create the brick was already clipped to Kenya. These two files work fine in MaxEnt. I am not sure why I am getting the error at the end.

```
locations<-read.csv("M:/GISKenya/latlon locations.csv")
plot(locations)

climdat<-brick("M:/GISKenya/Kenya_ASCII/bioclim19_asc.asc")
plot(climdat)

occur.ras<-rasterize(locations, climdat, 1)
plot(occur.ras)
cellStats(occur.ras, sum)

presences<-which(values(occur.ras) == 1)
pres.locs<- coordinates(occur.ras)[presences, ]

dens <-kde2d(pres.locs[,1], pres.locs[,2], n = c(nrow(occur.ras), ncol(occur.ras)))
dens.ras<-raster(dens)
plot(dens.ras)

writeRaster(dens.ras, "M:/GISKenya/Amblyvar bias file4.asc")
```

```
Error in .startAsciiWriting(x, filename, ...) : 
  x has unequal horizontal and vertical resolutions. Such data cannot be stored in arc-ascii format
```

Comment: Check `res(dens.ras)` as your horizontal and verticle cell resolutions are not the same and must be for an asc raster format. If your extent is the same you can likely just assign the resolution eg., `res(dens.ras) <- c(30,30)`

Comment: @JeffreyEvans wouldn't reassiging the `res` like that mess up the raster geometry in some bad way, unless the res was very close to (30,30) anyway? In which case I'd expect it to be within the tolerance of writeRaster for ASC files...

Comment: I *think* what is happening is that `kde2d` is working on a set of points that are *inside* the extent of your raster, and so producing an output that has the same number of rows and columns as your raster, but with a smaller extent. I think if you set the `lims` parameter of `kde2d` to match the extent of your raster then the output will match your input raster and -- assuming that input was square pixels -- it can then be written to an ASC file.

Comment: @Spacedman, so true, my bad. I need to not comment on my phone. I had a student with a very similar issue that was traced back to raster arbitrarily assigning a different x,y pixel resolution. We were able to just reassign it without changing the extent nor row/col dims. It was, in fact, throwing an error writing to asc with the different x,y res. Ironically, I have a function `spatialEco::sp.kde` that accounts for exactly this effect, allowing for a reference raster for unweighted or weighted KDE.

Answer (score 0):

Its always a good idea to set up a simple small example you can check visually what's going on. Let's make a 10x10 pixel matrix:

```
library(MASS)
library(raster)

r = raster(matrix(1:100,10,10))
r[] = 0
set.seed(123)
r[sample(ncell(r), ncell(r)/8)]=1
plot(r)
```

[image]

```
> r
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 10, 10, 100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.1, 0.1  (x, y)
extent     : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

Note that the full extent of the image is (0,1) on both axes - that goes to the outer edge of the pixels and is not the coordinates of the pixels at the edges. Also note that the resolution is 0.1, 0.1, which means these are square pixels and we can write them to an ASC file. Your input `occur.ras` came from an ASC file so it should also have square pixels like this.

Now let's work with that the way you have:

```
occur.ras = r

presences<-which(values(occur.ras) == 1)
pres.locs<- coordinates(occur.ras)[presences, ]

dens <-kde2d(pres.locs[,1], pres.locs[,2], n = c(nrow(occur.ras), ncol(occur.ras)))
dens.ras<-raster(dens)
```

What does that give us for an output density raster?

```
> dens.ras
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 10, 10, 100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.1, 0.08888889  (x, y)
extent     : 0, 1, 0.005555556, 0.8944444  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

its 10x10 pixels, but the extent is not the same as the input raster. This is because `kde2d` has worked to the extent of your input points, and there's no points on the top row of the raster, so its not the same extent. Writing as an ASC file fails:

```
> writeRaster(dens.ras,"foo.asc")
Error in .startAsciiWriting(x, filename, ...) : 
  x has unequal horizontal and vertical resolutions. Such data cannot be stored in arc-ascii format
```

To make `kde2d` return output to the same basis as your input raster, you need to specify the number of cells and the limits via the `lims` parameter, but you have to correct for the cell width and height because `kde2d` works on point locations rather than full extent. Try this:

```
e = extent(occur.ras)
re = res(occur.ras)
xw = re[1]/2
yw = re[2]/2
dens <-kde2d(pres.locs[,1], pres.locs[,2],
             n = c(nrow(occur.ras), ncol(occur.ras)),
             lims = c(e[1]+xw,e[2]-xw,e[3]+yw,e[4]-yw))
dens.ras<-raster(dens)
```

Now `dens.ras` should have the same grid basis as `occur.ras`:

```
> dens.ras
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 10, 10, 100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.1, 0.1  (x, y)
extent     : 6.938894e-18, 1, 6.938894e-18, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

and up to arithmetic rounding (10^-18) it does. This should now write as an ASC file:

```
> writeRaster(dens.ras,"density.asc")
>
```